How to solve Dompdf mb_internal_encoding
I am trying to generate a pdf using dompdf which works well on local server (XAMPP) But when i go live (CPANEL) i get this error  **Fatal

error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in /home/calbrema/public_html/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php on line 295
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in /home/calbrema/public_html/dompdf/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php on line 295**. Here is whats on line 295

$this->mbstringEncoding = mb_internal_encoding();
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); 

I am using Php 8.3 on shared Cpanel hosting. I checked under php extensions and mbstring is ticked.
How do i solve this please help
I tried adding this extension=php_mbstring.dll in php.ini as stated in one of the forums here which doesn't seem to working at all.

Check if mbstring is available via phpinfo().

@Olivier I cannot see it anywhere under Directive

@Olivier found it, Multibyte decoding support using mbstring disabled
It says disabled, how do i enable that?
Not sure if its the one though

"Multibyte decoding support using mbstring" comes from the exif extension. Search for the mbstring section. In this section Multibyte Support should be enabled.

@1stthomas it is disabled i may have to contact the Hosting Company as its not working via php.ini file
